# Why does this code to change from data.frame to matrix not work for mode "qn"?

Tags: r, matrix

Actually, for other modes, x=as.matrix(x) is working well, but for the mode="qn", it's not working and triggered an error. 
like this :

```r
mm.norm(iris[1:4],"qn")
```

> Error in apply(x, 2, rank, ties.method = "first") :    dim(X) must
>   have a positive length

iris is the dataframe

and the code is

```
function(x, mode, na.rm=FALSE){
if(class(x)=="data.frame"){
    x = as.matrix(x)
} 
if(class(x)=="matrix"){
    return (apply(x,2,mm.norm, mode=mode, na.rm=na.rm))
}
if (mode =="uv"){
    x = x/sd(x, na.rm=na.rm)
}
else if (mode =="fs"){
    x = ((x-min(x)/max(x)-min(x)))
}
else if (mode =="qn"){
    x.rank= apply(x,2, rank, ties.method="first")
    x.sort=apply(x,2, sort)
    x.mean= apply(x.sort,1,mean)
    itm<-function(x.rank,x.mean){
        return(x.mean[x.rank])
    }
    x=apply(x.rank,2,itm,x.mean)
}
else if (mode =="z"){
    x = (x-mean(x))/sd(x, na.rm=na.rm)
}
else{stop(paste("unknow mode", mode))}
return(x)
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the error.

Comment: @MartinGal sry just edited, and added the error

Comment: @MartinGal oh yeah you are right..i just fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there error is here:

```r
if(class(x)=="matrix"){
    return (apply(x,2,mm.norm, mode=mode, na.rm=na.rm))
}
```

To be honest, I don't know why this part of code is here, perhaps you can remove it. The first if-statement checks the input (matrix: yes/no). The second runs the function recursive, but I don't understand why.

But, I'm curious: your mode `fs`: are you sure, it's

```
((x-min(x)/max(x)-min(x)))
```

I don't know what you are supposed to do, but I would have expected

```r
(x-min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
```

Comment: I tried to code for feature scaling and you are right, my code equation is wrong and fixed it to yours.

Comment: one last thing! I asked about this ("what is different between two codes") last time and you kindly answered me. According to the answer from this question, the result from dh.norm is wrong, and the result from ml.norm is correct?

Comment: To be honest: I don't know. I don't know where you got the functions from and what your task really is about. I'm just suspicious about that recursive call of `mm.norm` and I guess here is a problem. But seriously: I don't know.